# Calculate average values with group-by java 8 lambda streaming

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, grouping

I have an object list which contains 2 attributes (`date and an integer value`). I am trying to write a java 8 lambda function to filter the list in a way that the average value of the time between `2.00 and 4.00` should be calculated separately and the values between `4.01 and 6.00` calculate separately regardless of the date

```
public class Obj{
  private Date date;
  private int value;
}
```

example object mapping is as follows

```
[
{
 date: '2010-02-01 2.00',
 value: 20
},
{
 date: '2010-02-01 4.00',
 value: 5
},
{
 date: '2010-02-02 3.00',
 value: 55
},
{
 date: '2010-02-02 3.30',
 value: 7
},
{
 date: '2010-02-03 5.00',
 value: 88
},
{
 date: '2010-02-03 5.20',
 value: 1
}
]
```

In here, value `20, 5, 55, 7` should be calculate separately since those are there when the date value is between 2.00 and 4.00
similarly `88 and 1` should be calculated separately since those values are places when the time is 4.01 and 6.00

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want; could you explain step-by-step?

Comment: Sounds like you're on your way and you have a good idea of what you want. It would be helpful to provide code examples to where you're failing so that people can help fix your errors rather than solve problems for you ;). Consider reading about creating a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

In order to simple the code.change your Obj class like this

```
class Obj {
    private String date;
    private int value;
}
```

and the data only contains the hour

The group and reduce code as follow：

```
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(new Function<Obj, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer apply(Obj o) {
                return (int) Float.parseFloat(o.getDate()) / 4;
            }
        }, Collectors.summarizingInt(new ToIntFunction<Obj>() {
            @Override
            public int applyAsInt(Obj value) {
                return value.getValue();
            }
        }));
```